# Count post that have specific meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, count

How do I count only the post that have a specific custom meta field value?

```
$productCount = wp_count_posts('product');
echo $productCount->publish;
```

That gives me all the total of all the post.

How do I find out how many of those post have say a custom meta value of `cat`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no default/native function in wordpress to count posts from a specific meta value. [`wp_count_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts) only counts the amount of posts according to post type

It might be useful here to use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to create a custom query to get all posts with that specific meta value and then use `$wp_query->found_posts` to get the post count.

This should do it

```
 $query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'color', 'meta_value' => 'blue' ) );

   echo $query->found_posts;
```

Comment: This answer is probably the first idea that comes to mind. However, this may turn to be extensive in terms of resource usage (RAM). In such use cases, it's best to go for a SQL query through `global $wpdb`

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to do this is by:

```
global $wpdb;
$count = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(*) AS THE_COUNT FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE (meta_key = 'color' AND meta_value = 'blue')");

return $count->THE_COUNT;
```

Here's a collection of functions to make it easier to use:

```
    /**
     * Returns the number of posts a particular metakey is used for.
     * Optionally qualified by a specific value or values in an array of the meta key.
     *
     * @param string            $key
     * @param null|string|array $value
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    function get_meta_count( $key, $value = null) {
        global $wpdb;

        $where = get_meta_where($key, $value);
        $count = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(*) AS THE_COUNT FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE $where");
        return $count->THE_COUNT;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the postmeta records for a particular metakey.
     * Optionally qualified by a specific value or values in an array of the meta key.
     *
     * @param string            $key
     * @param null|string|array $value
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    function get_meta ( $key, $value = null) {
        global $wpdb;
        $where = get_meta_where($key, $value);
        return $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE $where");
    }

    /**
     * Returns the where string for a metakey query
     *
     * @param string            $key
     * @param null|string|array $value
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function get_meta_where( $key, $value) {
        $where = "meta_key = '$key'";

        if (null !== $value) {
            if (\is_array($value)) {
                \array_walk($value,'add_quote');
                $in = \implode(',', $value);  // Seperate values with a comma
                $where .= " AND meta_value IN ($in)";
            } else {
                $where .= " AND meta_value = '$value'";
            }
        }

        return $where;
    }

    /**
     * Puts quotes around each value in an array when used as a callback function
     *
     * @param $value
     * @param $key
     */
    function add_quote( &$value, $key)
    {
        $value = "'$value'";
    }
```

Comment: There's a typo in the first SQL command - missing a single quote at the end of "blue" - submitted an edit.