# Count custom post types with a specific meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, count

We have a custom type called `books`. In a template, we need to show the counts of books that have the `book_type` as

1. Fiction
2. Non Fiction
3. Novel
4. Short Stories

We use ACF Pro, and the above field is set up as a checkbox multiple selection. So a book can be Fiction + Short Stories, Fiction + Novel, etc. We need to count only Fiction.

This does *not* work, as found in another [suggested thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149925/count-post-that-have-specific-meta-value) here:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'book_type', 'meta_value' => 'Fiction' ) );
$fiction = $query->found_posts;
```

I don't have enough points to comment there, so it's better I suppose to create a new ticket.

Also found a [thread on the ACF forums](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/count-custom-fields-with-specific-value/), but the code suggested there doesn't work either. I use latest WP, latest ACF Pro (5.8.x).

Welcome any thoughts on how to do this.

Comment: You have to use meta query like: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/159433/138292

Comment: This type of data would be much better suited to a Taxonomy. Then you can easily get the post count as it's stored alongside the taxonomy terms as `$term->post_count`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I suppose its you who downvoted my anwser ? May I ask you why ? It does the requested job, no ?

Comment: @Gregory You make several points in your answer that are inaccurate: They shouldn't use LIKE, a full `meta_query` is not necessary, and `posts_per_page` does not need to be `-1` when using `found_posts`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks for the reply, but i really don't think it has to be downvoted for those reason. Maybe just add a comment, & i will edit with your suggestions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st. you need to add post_type to your query, then you need to filter meta_value with LIKE. Finaly, you need to add posts_per_page as -1 to get ALL posts.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'books',
    'meta_query' => array(
                     array(
                        'key'     => 'book_type',
                        'value'   => 'Fiction',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    )
                ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$fiction = $query->found_posts;
```